# Extend/append a nested list of arbitrary size with another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, append, nested-lists

List of List which will be unknown in length of lists, *this is an example*

```
a = [['GigabitEthernet0/0,', '0'], ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1,', '0']]
```

List of unknown strings in list, *this is an example*

```
b =['4564325', '777']
```

Is it possible in order to numerically extend **a** with the corresponding string from **b**?

Desired result below

```
[['GigabitEthernet0/0,', '0', '4564325'], ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1,', '0', '777']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` them and append one to the other within a loop.

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
     x.append(y)

print(a)
[['GigabitEthernet0/0,', '0', '4564325'],
 ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1,', '0', '777']]
```

---

Using a `list comprehension`:

```
a = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(a)
[['GigabitEthernet0/0,', '0', '4564325'],
 ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1,', '0', '777']]
```

---

Interesting `map` alternative:

```
a = map(list.__add__, a, [[i] for i in b]) # python2.7
print(a) 
[['GigabitEthernet0/0,', '0', '4564325'],
 ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1,', '0', '777']]
```

Comment: Amazing this worked perfectly. Could you answer one question regarding the list comprehension. a = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(a, b)], why the [y]?

Comment: @BarryKeegan `y` is a string. I cannot add a string to a list (`x` is a list here because `a` is a list of lists). Same logic follows in the `map` solution where I convert `b` to a list of lists...

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you again, makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.